# find certain item of a file by using command line tool in windows 7

Tags: command-line, find, findstr

recently I used

```
findstr "ItemThatIsBeeingSearchedFor" C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts > J:\documents\HostsFile\ResultOfSearch.txt
```

in order to output a certain entry of the hosts file into a .txt. now I am trying to do the same with

```
findstr "conversion" j:\documents\post_01 > j:\documents\conversion.txt
```

to output terms with the string 'conversion' in their names, but that doesn't work. the output .txt is empty. what am I doing wrong? os: win 7 ult 64bit.

Comment: Use `/I` Parameter to make the search Case insensitive. Other than that maybe conversion is not in the file at all.

Comment: You can try as well with command `type file.txt | find /I "conversion" > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I find files where the filename contains a specified string?

You used `findstr`. However, `findstr` is used to search for strings in files, not strings in the filename itself.

To find filenames containing a certain string you should use `dir` ("Display a list of files and folders").

Try the following command:

```
dir j:\documents\post_01\*conversion* > j:\documents\conversion.txt
```

Sources

- [DIR Display a list of files and subfolders](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [FINDSTR Search for strings in files.](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.